# Infinite loop while listing linked list

Tags: c

The problem is on while loop. I couldn't find what's wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

typedef struct node {
        int data;
        node *next;
        };

int main(){
 node * root= (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
 node * temp = root;
 for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
         temp->data=i*10;
         temp->next=(node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
         temp=temp->next;
         }     
 temp =root;
 while(temp){ //infinite loop
         printf("\n%d",temp->data);
         temp=temp->next;       
         }
         getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Infinite loop or does it hang? (I'd guess the latter) -- your final temp->next is undefined and likely sends your program off into the Twilight Zone

Comment: Am I the only one who **loves** the idea of an "infinitive loop"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You never set the last nodes next to null. Put
`temp->next = NULL;`
 after the for loop.

When you allocate node with malloc, values are not initialized to anything. So `next` points to some random place in the memory.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably missing this last line in your list building loop:

```
    /* ... */
    temp->next = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you allocate the last node, you never set its `next` pointer.  Since it is uninitialized, it will contain whatever data was already in that memory location, which is almost certainly not NULL.  After you've processed all the nodes in the `while` loop, your program will dereference this uninitialized pointer and invoke undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're compiling `C`?

In the for loop, initialize the `next` pointer to NULL.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    /* ... */
    temp->next = malloc(sizeof (node));
    assert(temp->next && "no memory"); /* easy test of malloc return value */
    temp->next->next = NULL;
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Inside the loop. Right after the test for malloc. The 3 lines above should all stay together.

Answer (score 0):

this is because `while (temp)` always contains a value.
Make sure your last node points to a NULL value so that `temp=temp->next;` will return NULL and exits the loop.